# Are requests for theme suggestions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I was about to post a question requesting help finding a theme that matches certain criteria, but felt like it might be borderline off-topic and might be construed as a poll question. Clearly if I worded it like "Whats a good theme for my blog?" it should get closed quickly, but if I am very specific about my requirements it seems like more of a gray area.

Before I submitted it I thought I'd ask the meta-community if it is acceptable.

Here's a pro-forma example of the type of question I am asking about

> I've been looking for a new theme for
>   my WP blog and finding the search
>   functionality lacking on many of the
>   theme marketplaces and theme vendor
>   sites. Can you recommend a theme
>   that meets these criteria?
>
> - Three column
> - Liquid/flexible layout
> - Prominent commenting features
> - Layout to display one blog post per page
> - Custom header banner image support
> - Tabbed layout.

I realize I could just post the question and throw it to the wolves to devour or adopt and raise with the pack. However, I thought it worth discussion as to whether highly specific theme recommendation requests are on topic for the site.

Comment: Just FYI, almost *all* of those criteria are built into the [WPORG Theme Repository filter search](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/tag-filter/).

Comment: @Chip Thanks, I didn't know about that site.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this would make a good question, but not simply because it's about looking for theme. As for me it's because your question is overly specific for your needs.

Sanity check:

- how probable do you think for someone who knows **exactly such** theme to stumble on your question?
- how likely it is for any other person in the future to need **exactly such** theme and benefit from your question?

The problem with such question (that we constantly have with [plugin-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-recommendation)) is that while the need for answer is genuine, the practical success in getting good answers is quite poor.

So my personal recommendation would be to focus on use-case rather than overly specific features.

So lets rehash your question with this in mind:

> I am looking for theme for (blogging? portfolio? eshop?) and would like it to be capable of following functionality:
>
> - <del>Three column</del>
> - <del>Liquid/flexible layout</del> Three column layout with liquid center
> - <del>Prominent commenting features</del>
> - <del>Layout to display one blog post per page</del> *(any theme can, with minor tweak at most)*
> - <del>Custom header banner image support</del>
> - up to date, with modern WP features (namely threaded comments, custom header)
> - <del>Tabbed layout.</del> *(of what? makes no sense)*

See what I mean? Now it looks much less like *do-my-research-for-me* and much more like other people might find useful in the long run.

Comment: Up-voting your answer, but just wanted to add that, IMHO, such questions are out-of-scope because the question and answer provide *absolutely no benefit whatsoever* to the community.

Comment: @Chip Bennett I disagree on _absolutely_. Question on theme for some specific task (but probably not generic blogging) can be beneficial just fine.

Comment: but *Themes* aren't *task* (i.e. functionality) specific. Most Theme request questions normally boil down to 1) Use the tag filter, and 2) Find a Plugin to integrate desired functionality. To that end, **I actually could see Plugin suggestion questions as more likely to be more-generally useful** to the community. Let me be clear: Theme questions are not inherently out of scope, but I think questions of "here are my unique/specific needs; what Theme should I use" generally *should* be out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to make this valuable for the community. Don't ask for a specific theme, but ask for Starter / Templates themes?

These are re-usable by the community, and knowing which ones are more widely used or better would be beneficial. So I only use these requirements

> I am looking for theme for (blogging? portfolio? eshop?) and would like it to be capable of following functionality:
>
> - Three column layout with liquid center
> - up to date, with modern WP features (namely threaded comments, custom header, and other wp3 features)